# Python 3 with SQL insert query results in error "column count doesn't match value count at row"

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to upload data from a csv file (its on my local desktop) to my remote SQL database. This is my query

```
dsn = "dsnname";pwd="password"
import pyodbc
csv_data =open(r'C:\Users\folder\Desktop\filename.csv')

def func(dsn):

    cnnctn=pyodbc.connect(dsn)
    cnnctn.autocommit =True
    cur=cnnctn.cursor()


    for rows in csv_data:

        cur.execute("insert into database.tablename (colname) value(?)", rows)


    cur.commit() 
    cnnctn.commit()
    cur.close()
    cnnctn.close()
    return()

c=func(dsn)
```

The problem is that all of my data gets uploaded in one col- that I specified. If I don't specify a col name it won't run. I have 9 cols in my database table and I want to upload this data into separate cols.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert with SQL, you need to make sure you are telling which columns you want to be inserting on. For example, when you execute:

```
INSERT INTO table (column_name) VALUES (val);
```

You are letting SQL know that you want to map column_name to val for that specific row. So, you need to make sure that the number of columns in the first parentheses matches the number of values in the second set of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for answering- but in my case, how can I specify with insert. So the csv file has like 1200 rows or more sometimes. How can I state my sql query that accounts for each column

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want it to dynamically insert based on the columns of the csv?

Comment: Yes. so lets say i have 9 columns in the table im inserting and 9 in my file. I want to insert those columns from the file. so what im asking is do i have to write names of all columns?also how to get values.